# Confused about databases vs collections

Tags: mongodb, database

I am new to mongo and currently trying to set up my project's database with the mongo shell. I understand conceptually that a collection is like a table, and databases house collections.

I am confused about the following:

- is 'db' my database I'm working in? I read that the initial database is 'test' and 'db'. Which one is it?
- When I use a command like `db.bears.find()`, Is bears a database or collection? When I use both commands `show dbs` and `db.getCollectionNames()`, bears is listed in both! How can they be collections and databases?
- Is nested databases possible?

Comment: I personally think every beginner in MongoDB must read [Glossary](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/) it will help to understanding MongoDB more

Comment: In the Mongo shell, the `db` object is your _current_ database.

Comment: I did read the glossary. I had a hard time translating what I read there to what I was seeing in the mongo shell.

Comment: A short tutorial will help you separate the differences between the name `db` in the JS console and the actual db name of `test`. I would try googling about a bit for a basic JS 101, it will help a lot

Comment: Thanks, but the tutorials I found related to mongo all seem to talk about how to CRUD documents. I am actually a javascript professional, so a JS101 course wouldn't help.

Comment: This is JavaScript tutorials, wipe away the mongo part and just look at the JS syntax and read up on that. That should help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is 'db' my database I'm working in? I read that the initial database
>   is 'test' and 'db'. Which one is it?

`db` refers to the database you are currently using. By default, when you first open mongo, that database is called `test`.

You can switch to a different database (called test2 for example) like this:

```
>use test2
switched to db test2
```

Now `db` will refer to `test2`, the new database that you are using.

> When I use a command like 'db.bears.find()', Is bears a database or
>   collection? When I use both commands 'show dbs' and
>   'db.getCollectionNames()', 'bears is listed in both! How can they be
>   collections and databases?

When you write `db.bears.find()` bears in that command is a collection. If bears is appearing in both `show dbs` and `db.getCollectionNames()` that means you have a collection called bears and a database called bears. They are two separate entities.

> Is nested databases possible?

If I understand your question correctly, no it's not possible.

Comment: Great thanks. I didn't understand db was a reference for the current database.

Comment: You're welcome :) I noticed that you didn't accept this as the answer, do you have a followup question?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to asking questions here. I usually find what I need by lurking. Answer accepted.